# How to parse string as local date and convert it to UTC in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a log that I want to parse and, among other things, convert the date/time from the current local format to UTC and convert it back to text.

I have the logic to do everything except the conversion part.

```
$_.Line -replace '(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})',(conversion_here)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the [`regex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class with a callback function:

```
$fmt = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
$callback = {
  (Get-Date $args[0].Groups[1].Value).ToUniversalTime().ToString($fmt)
}
$re = [regex]'(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'

...
$re.Replace($_.Line, $callback)
...
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  Beautiful solution with the callback.  I didn't know this could be done.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [DateTime] object for this:

```
([DateTime]'2015-07-03 10:58:00').Date.ToUniversalTime()
```

For your replacement scenario, you could use:

```
$pattern = '(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'
if ($line -match $pattern) {
    $utcStr = ([DateTime]$matches[1]).ToUniversalTime().ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
    $line -replace $pattern, $utcStr
}
```