# Substituting strings with environment variables in a file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
<Parameter Name="WebImage" Value="web:${BuildNumber}" />
<Parameter Name="ApiImage" Value="api:${BuildNumber}" />
```

I'd like to replace any occurrence of `${xxx}` in the file with the environment variable `xxx`.  This file could refer to any number of environment variables; they are not known ahead of time.

I'm trying something like:

```
(Get-Content .\Cloud.xml) -replace "\$\{(\w+)\}", "$([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('$1'))"
```

However, I just get:

```
<Parameter Name="WebImage" Value="web:" />
<Parameter Name="ApiImage" Value="api:" />
```

The `GetEnvironmentVariable` call works, since I can do:

```
(Get-Content .\Cloud.xml) -replace "\$\{(\w+)\}", "$([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('BuildNumber'))"
```

And that works.  The `$1` call works since I can do:

```
(Get-Content .\Cloud.xml) -replace "\$\{(\w+)\}", '$1'
```

And I'll get:

```
<Parameter Name="WebImage" Value="web:BuildNumber" />
<Parameter Name="ApiImage" Value="api:BuildNumber" />
```

However, I can't seem to combine the two.  I think it's something to do with the order of how functions are resolved.

Comment: PowerShell expands `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable()` long before the regular expression engine gets to see the replacement string and could fill in `$1`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yea that's kinda what I figured.  I need some way to build an expression by hand and then resolve it.  Kinda like an `eval()`

Comment: Please take a look at my answer to the duplicate question linked at the top of your question.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yup, basically that evaluates any expression in the entire file.  I'd have to change how I represent tokens, but it would work.  Thanks!

Comment: You could also parse the XML and apply the string expansion only to a particular node or attribute value (basically a combination of the first and last code snippet from my answer).

Comment: Another option might be a replacement using a [callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31211494/1630171).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `$Matches` auto variable.

```
(Get-Content .\Cloud.xml) | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        if ($_ -match "\$\{((\w+))\}")
        {
            $_ -replace "\$\{(\w+)\}",$([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable($Matches[1]))
        }
        else
        {
            $_
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a solid answer because it lets me express my own token format and would work with any file (not just XML).  I have a feeling it could be made simpler though..

Comment: @MikeChristensen, I have placed an extra `()` for match condition to make groups and now it comes a little shorter and simpler too.